# MySql update record after finding duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I've successfully created a SQL query that finds duplicates in my table like this:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) c FROM subscribers GROUP BY email HAVING c > 1 ;
```

This table also has columns "unsubscribed" and "bounced" and "complaint".

The default is '0' for these columns with a '1' when a users has opted out.

If one of the duplicates found in my SELECT has a '1' in any of these columns, I need to update the other duplicate records with a '1' for that column, in that record.

Comment: Can you please also post some sample data along with expected result *after* the `UPDATE` has taken place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this with a self-join:

```
select *
from subscribers s
  inner join subscribers i
    on s.email = i.email
      and s.id <> i.id
where 1 in (s.unsubscribed,s.bounced,s.complaint)
  and (
       i.unsubscribed<>s.unsubscribed
    or i.bounced<>s.bounced
    or i.complaint<>s.complaint
    )
```

For the update I would probably just do this to cover all cases where 1 record might be unsubscribed and another record for the same email might be a complaint, etc:

```
update subscribers s
  inner join (
    select 
        email
      , max(unsubscribed) as unsubscribed
      , max(bounced)      as bounced
      , max(complaint)    as complaint
    from subscribers as i
    group by email
    having count(*)>1 
    ) as a
      on a.email = s.email
set s.unsubscribed = a.unsubscribed
  , s.bounced      = a.bounced
  , s.complaint    = a.complaint;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/RGOG61470

You could change the `having` to:

```
having count(*)>1 
  and (min(unsubscribed)<>max(unsubscribed)
    or min(bounced)     <>max(bounced)
    or min(complaint)   <>max(complaint)
       )
```

To further restrict the update to only those that have different values for at least one of those three columns.

Comment: That seems to work great, how do I turn this into an UPDATE too?